# First person jumping with rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Im trying to make a simple FPS player movement with rigid body. The code below works for moving with WASD but for jumping its a bit weird. When pressing space, the character jumps so little and kind of jerks. I'd figure there's something wrong with the Move() function because if I comment that part out, the jumping works fine.

```
public LayerMask groundMask;
public Transform groundCheck;
public Rigidbody rb;
[Space]
public float speed;
public float jump;

private float x;
private float z;

private void Update()
{
    Move();
    Jump();
}

void Move()
{
    x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 move = (transform.right * x + transform.forward * z) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    rb.velocity = move;
}

void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsGrounded())
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jump, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}

bool IsGrounded()
{
    return Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, 0.1f, groundMask);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in `Move` you hard overwrite the `velocity`.

You rather want to keep the Y axis.

Also when dealing with a `velocity` this already **is** a value per second so here you don't want to apply `Time.deltaTime`.

```
void Move()
{
    x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    var move = (transform.right * x + transform.forward * z) * speed;

    move.y = rb.velocity.y;

    rb.velocity = move;
}
```

---

in general in order to not move faster diagonal I would rather suggest

```
// This will make sure that the total magnitude of the vector is maximum 1
var input = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(transform.right * x + transform.forward * z, 1f);
move = input * speed;
move.y = rb.velocity.y;

rb.velocity = move;
```

Comment: ahh, good to know. thank you!